# The difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` in the declaration of a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-literals

I have the following function in C:

```
int TransMinMaj(char *c)
{
    if((*c) >= 'a' && (*c) <= 'z')
    {
        *c += 'A' - 'a';
        return 1;
    }
    else if((*c) >= 'A' && (*c) <= 'Z')
        return 1;
    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, this function:

1. Return 1 if the character tested is a letter

2. Transform the lower case to upper case

3. Otherwise, return 0 (to indicate that it is not a letter)

I have chosen to pass the parameter by address because I want to change the value of the passed parameter `c` in the memory.

Now my question comes:
I tested my function withe the following code :

```
char str[] = "abcdefg";
printf("Before: %s\n", str);    
TransMinMaj(&str[1]);
printf("After: %s\n", str);
```

Until now, everything is good, no errors, no warnings. And as you can see, in this test, I transforme the lower case letter `b` (also the second element of the string (array of characters)) to the upper case letter 'B' in the memory.

But, if change the test code a litte bit:

```
char *str = "abcdefg";
printf("Before: %s\n", str);    
TransMinMaj(&str[1]);
printf("After: %s\n", str);
```

There is a segmentation error(core dumped). 
But I don't know why. 

**So here comes my question:


1. What is the difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` in a declaration ?

 
2. Where does my segmentation error come from?**

Comment: Please use search before asking questions. It is very likely that your question has been asked before. This one has been asked since the beginning of time.

Comment: With the pointer you can do: ptr1=ptr2; with the array not. With the pointer you can do ptr1++; with the array not. With the array you can call sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) with the pointer not. And such things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char str[] = "abcdefg";
```

and

```
char *str = "abcdefg";
```

are two different things.

- The first one is an **array**, initialized with `"abcdefg"`.
- The second one is a pointer pointing to the **string literal** `"abcdefg"`.

In the second case, when you attempt to modify the string literal, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as any attempt to modify a string literal is UB.